# How to insert block into Article content type?

Tags: 7, nodes

I haven't found any option or module to achieve this yet.

I started to think I should do this by inserting code directly into article, but this would not be really good/easy solution on regular basis, for Adsense for example....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Insert Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_block)?

> Sidebar blocks contain all sorts of nifty stuff, but sometimes you
>   want to include or embed that stuff into the body of your node.
>   Instead of using PHP snippets (a possible security hole on public
>   sites), you can use this module. When it's activated...
>
> [block:name of module=delta of block]
>
> ...will insert the contents of a rendered sidebar block into the body
>   of your node. If no delta is specified, the default block for that
>   module will be displayed.

There's only dev releases for this module, but it has almost 6.000 installations.